# Set ZIndex for Google Fusion Tables in Google Maps API

Tags: google-maps, google-fusion-tables

Is there any way to set the ZIndex of a Google Fusion Table layer in the Google Maps API?  I have several Fusion layers added as overlays to a map with the ability to turn them on and off.  I want certain layers to always be ontop if they are on, however Fusion Tables/Google Maps just renders them in the order that they are drawn.

For example:

Layer 1 starts On.
Layer 2 starts Off. Layer 2 should Always be on top if it is being shown.

Click Layer 2 On, and it is on top.
Now, click Layer 1 Off and the On again, and now it is on top as it is the most recent layer drawn.

I'd ideally like to set the ZIndex of Layer 2 to higher than Layer 1 so that it is always on top, but there doesn't seem to be a way to do this.  Any ideas?

Comment: Did you find a solution to this problem? I have the same inquiry. I have multiple KML layers with one Google Fusion Table layer (point). When I click on the google fusion table layer points, I get the InfoWindow of the KML polygon layers rested on the same place.

Comment: I moved on to Leaflet maps. The link that @hugh gave references the fact that is implemented now. FYI - your "answer" should have been a comment on the main question, since it isn't really an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't see a method for doing this in the Google Maps API v3 reference, and that lack appears to be confirmed by this comment from a Google employee:

https://groups.google.com/d/msg/google-maps-js-api-v3/ovT1ekQ-HGQ/k-b8BSxCCjAJ

> FusionTablesLayer (and KmlLayer & co) don't have the ability to re-order based on z-index.

There is an active feature request for adding sorting by Z-Index for KML layers here:
http://code.google.com/p/gmaps-api-issues/issues/detail?id=2804

I am not aware of a corresponding feature request for FusionTableLayer objects, although perhaps the solving of one would facilitate the solving of the other.

Comment: I've worked around this with some clunky code to associate each possible layer with a Z value, then whenever a layer is added check which currently active layers have a higher Z value, delete them and redraw them in order. Which is obviously inefficient.

Comment: In the mean time, this has been added for kml layers, but not yet for fusion table layers. I created a new feature request for this: https://code.google.com/p/gmaps-api-issues/issues/detail?id=8869